# Question on Pandas Dataframe .loc / .iloc and String Operations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with  Pandas Dataframes and I am trying to do some String manipulation on particular cells.

For this task I loop through the dataframe, choose the needed cells with .loc, assign it to a variable and perform my string operations on this variable.

```
 for i in range(0,len(df_single)):
        firmenname_cics = df_single.loc[i,'FIRMENNAME_CICS'].to_string() 
        firmenname_fb = df_single.loc[i,'FIRMENNAME_FB'].to_string()
        .. firmenname_fb.stringOperation ..
```

My problem is, that the type of the variable is 'Series Object', so I have to convert it to string type before doing my operations. I read doc and the reason for this is becasue (in my example) `i` is not a integer value but a label of the index.

> (Quote from Pandas Doc: A single label, e.g. 5 or 'a', (**note that 5
>   is interpreted as a label of the index, and never as an integer
>   position along the index**).

So converting the 'Series Object' is not a huge problem, but I was wonderinng, if there a way to extract the value of a cell in String format? (like e.g. Excel VBA)

I have also looked at `.iloc` which kinda does the integer position thing for me, but seems to not let me access the needed column.

Comment: @mohanys - `you can paste them in HTML snippets` ? In pandas tag? Why? I think it is bad idea, text version is much better...

Comment: Correct. I was thinking about an easy way to explain for a newbie. If they put in the HTML snippets (for which there is a icon), it is automatically formatted. If they put it directly, they will have to format it. I get confused sometimes myself. If there is a link or something that explains it to new commers, let me know & i can includes this when i request this data (which i do a lot! :-))

Comment: @mohanys - Unfortunately I have only link - [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: I believe you have more than one row with the index "i" so you getting a series as an output. Still you can navigate through the series items with `.values[x]` or if you need all the items as a string so what you'r doing it's the way.

Comment: I tried my best guys :(

Comment: @Adirmola Correct! Thats what I just discoverd. I somehow messed up my indexes, because I am merging and appending some dataframes and somehow all my values get saved in index 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the particular column using iloc:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> mydict = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}, {'a': 100, 'b': 200, 'c': 300, 'd': 400},{'a': 1000, 'b': 2000, 'c': 3000, 'd': 4000 }]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)
>>> df
      a     b     c     d
0     1     2     3     4
1   100   200   300   400
2  1000  2000  3000  4000
>>> df.iloc[0]
a    1
b    2
c    3
d    4
Name: 0, dtype: int64
>>> df.iloc[0]["a"]
1
```